# Window Generator add-on not working properly

Tags: add-on

I hope this hasn't been answered already and I'm wasting everyone's time, I have downloaded the window generator 3 addon and when I go to use it, it just doesn't have all the tools that Andrew shows in one of his tutorials.

Did I download the wrong version? I added the folder that I unzipped to the "addons" folder and it now shows up under my mesh button but in the tools it only shows a tab that says Windows Generator and nothing else. It opens one window and that is it!

Any help would be appreciated. I am only 3 weeks into this and I'm loving it, but there is so much to learn!
Thanks!

Comment: Please add link to the tutorial / manual you're referring to and exact version of the addon, version of Blender and some screenshots (what you expect to be and what you have). If you mean [Window Generator 3](https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/tree/master/add_window_3) then that addon is now deprecated as it is included into the Archimesh addon which is already in Blender 2.79 by default (needs to be activated)

Comment: Thanks I believe you answered my question. The Archimesh works well enough for the windows I need. I wish there was a way to add more panels, arch windows etc. Thanks